# Using Background worker in c#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, msmq

Ive been trying to use a background worker in c# to help me use a MSMQ Program.

When the program loads it creates a new background worker called bgwMSMQ.

So far the code i have is:

```
    private void btnSendMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bgwMSMQ.IsBusy != true)
        {
            btnAbort.Enabled = true;
            btnSendMsg.Enabled = false;
            bgwMSMQ.RunWorkerAsync();
        }  
    }

    private void btnAbort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bgwMSMQ.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            btnAbort.Enabled = false;
            btnSendMsg.Enabled = true;
            bgwMSMQ.CancelAsync();
        }

    }
```

These are my Buttons

```
private void bgwMSMQ_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            /*txtPrevTiming.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                txtPrevTiming.Text = txtTiming.Text;
            });*/
            txtPrevTiming.Text = txtTiming.Text;
            ClearResponse();
            SendMessage(prepareMsg(txtMsgSent.Text), true, true);
        }
```

is the Do Work Code. The Aim of the program is to create a background process that will send and recieve a MSMQ Message. So far it works so that i can send a message and if it completes the send , recieve cycle there is no issues.

However i need to make it that if there is no message returned when i press the abort button it will stop listening to a response message instead of waiting for the timeout.

When i click abort it doesnt cancel the operation it sends a request to cancel it and im still stuck in the cycle and waiting for the response message to timeout.

Any idea's how to make this so that the abort button will cancel the operation of listening to a response message and stop the background worker ?

Thanks

```
try
            {

                int iObjId = (ObjectId.Length == 0) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(ObjectId);
                msgSend.Label = createLabel();
                //
                msgSend.BodyType = (int)VarEnum.VT_BSTR;
                msgSend.Body = SentMsg;
                //
                //sentMsg.BodyStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SentMsg));
                mqRequest.Send(msgSend);
                Stopwatch.Restart();
                String strMsgId = msgSend.Id;
                CorrelationId = msgSend.Id;
                if (!bGetResponse)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if (!getAnswer(ref mqResponse, CorrelationId, true))
                {
                    if (!getError(ref mqError, CorrelationId, true))
                    {
                        showError("Could not retrieve Response or Error");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                //showError.Invoke((Action<string>)delegate
                //{
                    showError(String.Format("Error \"{0}\" occurred when trying to send a message", ex.Message));
                //});
                return false;
            }
```

Is the send function, Sends a Message off and calls GetAnsewr which inturn calls RecieveByCorrelationID

Comment: Why did you comment-out the invoke part? And where is the code where you wait for the response? This doesn't look like the right job for a `BackgroundWorker`, btw. You can use a `Task` or the `ThreadPool` to execute a short task asynchronously.

Comment: IMHO, BackgroundWorker - Wrong choice, unless this is your first week in c#

Comment: I dont normally code in c# at all never had any experiance in it and this is effectivly my first time using it. The Invoke code was commented out as i was jus testing things its back in there now, The response code is buried in the SendMessage function. the Send message function sends the message then attempts to get a message back with the correlation ID. I tried using Task and async commands however it kept giving me an error saying i wasnt aloud to pass references in a task and i pass the Queue objects